# Can't run javafx JAR outside Netbeans

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, netbeans-7, javafx-8

I have a problem here with my javafx application jar, generated by Netbeans.
Actually everything is running pretty well IF I am running inside Netbeans. However when I use the command line and try to run the jar of my application which was previously created by Netbeans, using the command:

```
java -jar SequenceAlign.jar
```

I got a LOT OF errors in my terminal.
The error are the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

file:/Users/tsukanomon/NetBeansProjects/SequenceAlign/dist/SequenceAlign.jar!/sequencealign/bioGUI.fxml

   at sequencealign.bioGUIController.getMatrixSubNames(bioGUIController.java:110)
    at sequencealign.bioGUIController.populateComboSubMatrix(bioGUIController.java:99)
    at sequencealign.bioGUIController.initialize(bioGUIController.java:137)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2742)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2721)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2694)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2683)
    at sequencealign.SequenceAlign.start(SequenceAlign.java:21)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
     Exception in Application start method

 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:642)
at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sequencealign.bioGUIController.getMatrixSubNames(bioGUIController.java:110)
at sequencealign.bioGUIController.populateComboSubMatrix(bioGUIController.java:99)
at sequencealign.bioGUIController.initialize(bioGUIController.java:137)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2152)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2742)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2721)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2694)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2683)
at sequencealign.SequenceAlign.start(SequenceAlign.java:21)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:206)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
 2013-05-15 02:14:38.924 java[48780:2517] [JRSAppKitAWT markAppIsDaemon]:Process manager          already initialized: can't fully enable headless mode.   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.javafx.main.Main$2.run(Main.java:881)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:241)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
 Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1759)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1834)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1697)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:863)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:667)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:638)
... 19 more
```

My specifications are:

- Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.3
- java version "1.7.0_11"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
- Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
- Netbeans 7.2.1

Thanks for all the helping in advance!!!!!

Comment: r u trying to run the executable jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans wasn't importing all the necessary libs to run my application so I had to add manually some jar/library, even though I've already had added at the properties of my project.

Comment: You can import all your libs through netbeans also, use netbeans to deploy or create your jar and it will work perfectly.