# executable jar not opening when used with getResources (but works with an absolute file path) in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, jar, executable, getresource

**Problem:** 
Changing two lines of code makes the executable jar go from opening and working perfectly to not opening (even though it runs in Eclipse).

**Description:**
I have made an application in JavaFX using local file directories (silly I know) to access a .jpg file and I can deploy it as an executable and it works great on my computer using this code snippet.

Obviously, another computer will be unable to access my files so I converted the files into a more universal form so anyone who uses the application would be able to view the file.

A problem arises somehow when I create a .jar executable. The .jar opens and works great when using the absolute path but when I change only 2 lines the .jar executable will not open.

Here is the full code.

```
package workingSamples;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageDisplay extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("HTML");
    stage.setWidth(500);
    stage.setHeight(500);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    VBox root = new VBox();    

    final ImageView selectedImage = new ImageView(); 

    File file = new File( "C:\\Users\\Documents\\logo.jpg" );
    Image image1 = new Image( file.toURI( ).toString( ), 500, 200, true, true );

    //Image image1 = new Image(ImageDisplay.class.getResourceAsStream("logo.jpg"), 500, 200, true, true);        
    selectedImage.setImage(image1);

    root.getChildren().addAll(selectedImage);
    scene.setRoot(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

This .jar executes and opens with no errors but if I uncomment the one commented line (and comment out the two above it) the project works in Eclipse but it will not open any time when I export as an executable. And I get this error every time when I try to export it:

Exported with compile warnings: WorkingSamples/src/workingSamples/ImageDisplay.java

I have tried storing the data in both the bin and src, restarting Eclipse, making sure Debug mode is not running, trying every type of library handling. Maybe it is a permission issue but I do not know how to try to fix that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance :)

(I have tried the fixes from [javafx jar builds fine but doesn't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724921/javafx-jar-builds-fine-but-doesnt-open) (unfortunately I do not have command line access due to company security constraints) and [Can't run javafx JAR outside Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555281/cant-run-javafx-jar-outside-netbeans) (I don’t believe there are any libraries that need to be imported but are not) and [Unable to run Javafx from computer by double clicking the jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888458/unable-to-run-javafx-from-computer-by-double-clicking-the-jar-file) (I have the latest version of Java installed) and [Eclipse - error executable jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167513/eclipse-error-executable-jar-file) (I tried all library handling options but maybe it’s a permission issue which I do not know how to fix))

Code inspired from [this example:](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/LoadajpgimagewithImageanduseImageViewtodisplay.htm)

ANT file output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Create Runnable Jar for Project WorkingSamples with Jar-in-  Jar Loader" default="create_run_jar">
<!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR file Export Wizard-->
<!--ANT 1.7 is required-->
<!--define folder properties-->
<property name="dir.buildfile" value="."/><property name="dir.workspace" value="C:/Users /Documents/Eclipse"/><property name="dir.jarfile" value="${dir.buildfile}"/><target name="create_run_jar"><jar destfile="${dir.jarfile}/workingSamples7.jar"><manifest><attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader"/><attribute  name="Rsrc-Main-Class" value="workingSamples.ImageDisplay"/><attribute  name="Class-Path" value="."/><attribute name="Rsrc-Class-Path" value="./  org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_2.3.0.201603030809.jar"/></manifest><zipfileset  src="jar-in-jar-loader.zip"/><fileset  dir="${dir.workspace}/WorkingSamples/bin"/><zipfileset dir="C:/Users /Documents/   eclipse-java-mars-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins"    includes="org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_2.3.0.201603030809.jar"/></jar></target>   </project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base directory of `getResourceAsStream(...)` is your jar root. I would suggest to place your image into a resource folder (in your case) `WorkingSamples/resources/logo.jpg` afterwards you can access the image with

```
Image image1 = new Image(ImageDisplay.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/logo.jpg"), 500, 200, true, true);
```

Another thing you can check is if the ant script puts the image into the right place inside of the jar

Comment: Thank you for responding :). That helped eliminate the error (Exported with compile warnings: WorkingSamples/src/workingSamples/ImageDisplay.java) however I still cannot open the jar executable. I have my logo.jpg stored here: WorkingSamples\bin\workingSamples\resources and  use this line of code:  Image image1 = new Image(ImageDisplay.class.getResourceAsStream("/workingSamples/resources/BAE_logo.jpg"), 500, 200, true, true); Do you have an recommendations? Thanks again

Comment: Do you get any errors ? Without any erros is hard to guess whats going wrong. You path to the image looks wrong again, looks like you missed /bin, should look like this "/workingSamples/bin/resources/BAE_logo‌​.jpg"